# Can I put & in my String resource ?

Tags: android

I try to write 
Confirm & Close
in my String resources but I receive the following errors 
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this.......

```
<string name="confirm">Confirm &amp; Close</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you have to use HTML encoding:

```
&amp;
```

That's because & denotes a [character entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).